# How to avoid 'double select' on UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Here is the screen cap...of a tableView, the two blue cell, is selected.

[image]
How I simulated:
I select one tableCell, then, it pushes to the second view, and I back to the first view, and select the second tableCell, can it causes this issue. How can I resolve the problems? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going to the second view, deselect the cell:

```
[myTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

This will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` , call `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if the `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```